# How to get older version of Entity Framework with nuget?

Tags: entity-framework, nuget

I have a solution from someone else. In this solutions there are some nuget packages. When I run the nuget restore it doesn't retore all packages. One of them is Entity Framework. I can install it manually with nuget, but I see it will get version 5.

In the web.config I see this:

```
<section name="entityFramework" 
         type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" 
         requirePermission="false" />
```

I think I need Entity Framework version 4.4.0.0. Is this true? And how can I get this version with nuget?

Comment: If your assembly version is 4.4, it means you are using Entity Framework 5 on .NET Framework 4.0 (See also [this post/rant](http://www.bricelam.net/2012/10/unicorn-myths-debunked-entity-framework.html))

Answer (score 2):

Open Package manager console. type in

```
Install-Package Packagename -Version Versionnumber
```

remember to choose correct project in the package manager console.

Edit:
If your project is using .net 4 then you can get the EF 5 in nuget and it will get the 4.4 version for you because EF 5 can only be used in .net 4.5 or higher.

Comment: but I cannot find here my version 4.4.0.0: https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/

Comment: @user1326231 which .net version are you using. 4.0 or 4.5?

Comment: @user1326231 If your project is using .net version 4.0 you can just get entity framework version 5. then it will get the assembly version 4.4 for you. But if you are using .net 4.5 i would recommend to use the latest EF.